# Filter datatable with multiple column in where clause using lambda expression and VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I want to filter my datatable with multiple condition how to achieve using Lambda expression and VB.Net My sample code is as follow

```
Dim resultStyle = invData.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
                              .Where(Function(m) m.Field(Of Integer?)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleID").HasValue ) _
            .GroupBy(Function(v) New With {Key .InvestorStyleID = v.Field(Of Integer)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleID"), Key .StyleName = v.Field(Of String)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleName")}) _
            .Select(Function(v) New With {Key .InvestorStyleID = v.Key.InvestorStyleID, Key .StyleName = v.Key.StyleName, Key .Sum = v.Sum(Function(r) Double.Parse(r.Item("k001ICGeo").ToString()))})
```

i want to select only those data which "InstitutionalInvestorStyleID" not equal to null and with other column(Styleid column which can be multiple style id's)

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run your current code?

Comment: i am getting desired result but in where condition i want to add one more condition which should give me the result based on the styleid field in dataset. and also the style id can be multiple id's. Hope i am clear.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean, but in a lambda condition you can do this: `list.Where(Function(x) x.conditon1 AndAlso x.condition2)`